# All of a sudden NuGet issues Name or service not known retrying FinePackagesByIdAsync

Tags: nuget, gitlab-ci-runner, sonatype

With no changes, what so ever, NuGet all of a sudden is failing in the pipeline in the following maner:

$ dotnet test

[23](https://git.internal.mrsbpo.com/enterprisebackendservices/apiservices/-/jobs/25124#L23) Determining projects to restore...

[27](https://git.internal.xxxx.com/enterprisebackendservices/apiservices/project/-/jobs/25124#L27)/builds/7cjjzF-Y/1/enterprisebackendservices/project/callcomplianceapi/web.API.rules.Tests/web.API.rules.Tests.csproj : error NU1301: Unable to load the service index for source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json. [/builds/7cjjzF-Y/1/enterprisebackendservices/apiservices/project/web.API.Rules.sln]

[28] Retrying 'FindPackagesByIdAsync' for source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/amazon.lambda.aspnetcoreserver.hosting/index.json'.

[29] Name or service not known (api.nuget.org:443)

[30]Name or service not known

[31]Retrying 'FindPackagesByIdAsync' for source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/dapper.sqlbuilder/index.json'.

[32]Name or service not known (api.nuget.org:443)

etc etc etc...

Here is the pipeline

```
variables:
  # Update this for new version builds. - TODO: This will be removed at some point once Jim figures out automatic versioning based on git tags.
  VERSION: "1.0.$CI_PIPELINE_IID"
  VERSION_SUFFIX: "$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG-$CI_PIPELINE_IID-$CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA"
  # NOTE: If you change your package name, you should also change this to match.
  PACKAGE_NAME: "Reporting.HoldingQueueReport"

image: $CICD_IMAGE

stages:
  - test
  - deploy
  - deploy_runner

Test:
  stage: test
  before_script:
    - dotnet nuget add source $REPORTS_NUGET_SOURCE -n Nexus
    - "echo | dotnet --version" # must be v 2.2.300 or later for reporter tool to work
    - dotnet --info
    - dotnet restore --verbosity detailed
    - dotnet tool install dotnet-reportgenerator-globaltool --tool-path tools
  script:
    - dotnet test --logger "junit" --collect:"XPlat Code Coverage"
    # each reporttype must be a separate line, doesn't work together ; separated
    - ./tools/reportgenerator "-reports:${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/**/TestResults/*/coverage.cobertura.xml" "-targetdir:Reports_Coverage" -reportTypes:TextSummary;
    - ./tools/reportgenerator "-reports:${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/**/TestResults/*/coverage.cobertura.xml" "-targetdir:Reports_Coverage" -reportTypes:Html;
    - cat ./Reports_Coverage/Summary.txt
    - echo 'End Summary'
  coverage: /Line coverage[\s\S].+%/
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - Reports_Coverage/
    reports:
      junit:
        - "*.Test/TestResults/TestResults.xml"
        - "*.Tests/TestResults/TestResults.xml"

NuGet Publish:
  stage: deploy
  before_script:
    # Add our custom NuGet repository group so nuget restore works
    - dotnet nuget add source $REPORTS_NUGET_SOURCE -n Nexus
  script:
    # Pack the project into a NuGet package
    - dotnet pack -c Release -p:PackageVersion=${VERSION} -o ./build/packages --version-suffix "$VERSION_SUFFIX" --include-symbols

    - dotnet nuget push ./build/packages/**/*.symbols.nupkg -k ${NEXUS_NUGET_KEY} -s $REPORTS_DEPLOY_NUGET_SOURCE
  only:
    - master
```

So yes we use nexus Sonatype, but everyone seems fine.  Whats odd is that allowing v3 nuget to pass, now it works, but then will fail, but then work again, and then fail again.  Also when i say work, i still get the above error messages, but the pipeline will be fine.

Its very odd, that nothing was touched and nuget packages cannot be restored.  Is there any other way this can be done?

Comment: "Name or service not known" basically means DNS error. .NET's HttpClient is unable to figure out what IP address api.nuget.org maps to. I don't have any experience investigating flaky hardware or networking, but that's what the error message suggests.

Comment: i thought that as well, but i see others that says something about connections issues this one is just nothing.  but im feeling the same thing

Comment: I would expect NuGet to retry those failed requests. If it's not, I'd say it's a bug in NuGet. If it is retrying, there was a bug in older versions of NuGet where the retry would happen instantly, which is obviously bad for a transient network outage. Newer versions of NuGet should always wait at least 1 second between retries (unless overridden).  So, what version of the .NET SDK are you using on the machine that has these failures?

Comment: Any luck with this?
I have the same issue. Problems started yesterday without any change. I am using AWS pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

yes I had to do this

- dotnet nuget disable source nuget.org
- dotnet nuget add source https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/ -n oldnuget

as a work around.  not sure whats wrong with v3 in our environment